# What "it" means precisely in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

body tends to accumulate problems, often beginning with one small, seemingly minor imbalance.  This problem causes another subtle imbalance, which triggers another, then several more.  In the end, you get a symptom. **It** is like lining up a series of dominoes.  All you need to do is knock down the first one and many others will fall too.

What does it stand for?

Body's tendency to accumulate problems?

Comment: You want a capital letter on the first word of a sentence, but you also want an article or other determiner in front of *body* at the beginning, there. Missing the determiner and missing the capital letter looks like this is starting part-way through a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antecedent of ***it*** in this case is the entire scenario. The last two sentences are constructing a ***simile*** for the idea of small imbalances causing others until eventually there is a symptom; if you line up a domino run and set it going, it takes time to reach the end - and the end may produce something much more noticeable and spectacular than the simple fall of a few dominoes.

Pronounces like *it* and *this* don't necessarily refer to a simple noun, or even a basic noun phrase; they can refer to a whole set of interrelated concepts, a scenario, a situation.